# Solucionar error del contador de elementos en una lista

Tags: python

Buen día soy nuevo en python.

Necesito determinar cuántos son de  90 o más y asignar ese resultado a la variable ***high_scores***.

***scores = [67 80 90 78 93 20 79 89 96 97 92 88 79 68 58 90 98 100 79 74 83 88 80 86 85 70 90 100]***

¿Me pueden ayudar con mi código? Tengo un error y no sé como solucionarlo

```
for elementos in scores:
   if elementos >= 90:
       high_scores=elementos
       print(high_scores)
Contador = [list(high_scores).count(valores) for valores in set(high_scores)]
print(Contador)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

El error aparece porque tu variable `high_scores` es un entero y no una lista, por lo que no puedes ejecutar el método `count()` en un entero

Si solo te interesa saber el número de valores `>= 90` podrías hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
scores = [67, 80, 90, 78, 93, 20, 79, 89, 96, 97, 92, 88, 79, 68, 58 ,90, 98, 100, 79, 74, 83, 88, 80, 86, 85, 70, 90, 100]

Contador = 0
for elementos in scores:
    if elementos >= 90:
      high_scores = elementos
      Contador = Contador + 1
      print(high_scores)

print(Contador)
```